# How should I structure accepted invites?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

So I am working on an app for invites. People can send invites to their friends within the app and see who so far accepted the invites but the invites are grouped together if they are sent at the same time by the same person. I am having trouble structuring how I can get a list of who accepted the invites that are grouped together.

Right now I have a table for invites with an accepted field a sent_to_user_id field and a send_by_user_id field but I need to get a list of the users the accepted the invites.

I was thinking I need to make another table with an id field and then I would create a row in this new table and save the id that is created and then add that id to a field in the invites table and grab all the invites with that id where the accepted field is true. Is this a good way to structure this kind of relation or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: well assuming you have an `invite_id` field in the `invites` table, you can do `select sent_to_user_id from invites where invite_id = 'some invite' and accepted = true`

Comment: Well the trouble is I don't know what the invite_id is because there are multiple invites sent at the same time that should be grouped together when grabbing who accepted it... I'll add this to the post I guess I wasn't clear enough

Comment: I think you should make another field which is a group id for the invites. Then any invites that belong to a group of invites can be more easily identified.

Comment: Ok so should I just randomly generate a string for the group id and check if it already exists and if it does regenerate it until it doesn't exist? This sounds like a great solution I don't know why I thought I needed another table for this

Comment: What is the relevance of the group? We have a similar requirement. Our table has from_id, to_id, sent_date_time, status and accepted_date_time, among other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you don't give a lot of details here, but upon reading your question, the first design that came to my mind was:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
    id int not null,
    first_name text not null,
    last_name text not null
);

CREATE TABLE event(
    id int not null,
    event_name text not null,
    user_id int not null references user(id)
);

CREATE TABLE invite(
    id int not null,
    event_id int not null references event(id),
    user_id int not null references user(id),
    accepted boolean not null default false
);
```

note: the above has not been tested and should be considered pseudo-code, and doesn't include things like indexes.

This assuming that an invitation can only be created by the user that created the event. But, even if you have to add an `sent_by_user_id` field to the `invite` table, I would still just include an `accepted` field. From your OP, I don't see a reason why you need to split this out into another table.